# Running protractor test in chrome driver doest not opens up any website

Tags: javascript, protractor

```
System Details
Mac OS, Chromedriver v=83.0.4103.39 , Protractor=7.0
```

My test is failing all the time when chromedriver opens any website it says **your connection is not private** please let me know how to fix this issue
[chromedriver page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82QZ6.png)

My **spec.js** looks like below

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  it('should add a todo', function() {
      browser.get('https://angularjs.org');    
  });
});
```

**config.js** looks like below

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js'],
};
```

Comment: Are the requests passing through a proxy?

Comment: yes it passes through a proxy, no firewall

Comment: If the proxy tries to change the response, you get a certificate error like that.

Comment: not sure about this , but if its proxy issue then if I open chrome browser then none of these websites should work right but when I try to run my protractor test then I get this error "Your connection is not private"

Comment: These kinds of certificate errors only happen when something is interfering with the request, I think. I don't know what's happening in your case.

Answer (score 0):

this is how my proxies look like 
[proxy settings in mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esQVF.png)

Changes my config.js to 
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec1.js'],
  //acceptInsecureCerts : true
  'args': ['--disable-web-security', '--user-data-dir=~/.e2e-chrome-profile', '--ignore-certificate-errors'] 
};

Still any URL like facebook.com or google.com I am getting err_invalid_cert err